# E: Unable to locate package ea-utils | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, git-bash, sudo

I am following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/9BHY6NMkJs4?t=187). I already have `.fastq` files. I want to install [ea-utils](https://expressionanalysis.github.io/ea-utils/).

My setup is `Ubuntu 18.04 bionic`, via `Oracle VM Virtual Box`.

In `terminal`, I entered the command:

```
>>>sudo apt install ea-utils
E: Unable to locate package ea-utils
```

---

First, I installed latest `Ubuntu` updates via. `Software Updater`.

Then,

```
>>>sudo apt-get update
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Still throwing an error:

```
>>>sudo apt-get install ea-utils
Second command said: E: Unable to locate package ea-utils.
```

Comment: is this something you are trying to do in Git-Bash?

Comment: Yes, I will say this in my post

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install it using Git-Bash. Git-Bash is not a Linux environment (apt-get is a Linux utility that can be used in a Linux environment). Git-Bash is a subset of the MSYS (or MSYS2, not sure) collection of open source tools *compiled for Windows*

What you can try is

1. build your own version of `ea-utils` for Windows. [build guide](https://www.github.com/ExpressionAnalysis/ea-utils/tree/wiki/Compiling.md) - I will elaborate if required
2. check if there are any precompiled binaries for it

---

#### Expanding on building/compiling your own binaries of programs

1. Normally a program is written in a programming language (e.g C/C++, Java) that humans can read. These are plain text files.
2. That is **compiled** into something computers can read
3. This compiled file is *executable* on the platform which it is compiled for - ends in `.exe` for Windows
4. This executable file is distributed as a 'precompiled binary' that is copied into (usually) `C:\Program Files` by the installation procedure

**But things change in the world of open source software**

1. You are given the original files of code written in a programming language
2. You use a **compiler** combined with other **libraries** to compile it into an executable file
3. MinGW is a collection of tools, including the C/C++ compiler for Windows
4. [GSL](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm) is a library that provides some other code that ea-utils depends on for the compilation of the binaries

---

#### General instructions for building

(Sorry I cannot test these. I do not use Windows any more)

1. Install [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) - accepting the defaults should work fine
2. Install [GSL](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm) - try the link that says Setup (again, accept defaults)
3. Unzip the file you downloaded earlier from ea-utils' GitHub
4. Open command prompt
5. `cd` into the unzipped folder
6. (based on instructions on their wiki) `make`
7. `make test`

Comment: I have downloaded ea-utils as a .zip (at the link in post). I will update this if I am stuck further asap. Thanks guys

Comment: I'm feeling lost. The link you provided has another link http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm. Am I meant to install all these? @kevinnls

Comment: Update: I have now spun-up Debian Linux. Will get back to trying this at 7pm BST

Comment: with Debian, the `sudo apt-get` line should work just perfect. cheers!
if for some reason it doesn't, use: `sudo apt install ea-utils`

Comment: `sudo apt install ea-utils` and `sudo apt-get install ea-utils` both threw `E: Unable to locate package ea-tools`.

Comment: what did you mean when you said you have spun-up Debian Linux? i assumed you meant either a WSL(/2) or a VM or booted into a separate installation

Comment: Sorry, I am using Ubuntu, via Oracle VM Virtual Box

Comment: version of Ubuntu, please. and try running `sudo apt-get update` and follow it up with `sudo apt-get install ea-utils` again.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Answer (score 0):

Since your updated question is based on using Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM and you there is still an error, I suggest trying

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ea-utils
```

Commonly, software in the Linux word is distributed as "packages" - e.g `ea-utils`. The first command contacts Ubuntu's repositories (they serve the packages) and generates a list of all the available packages.

That *should* fix the error of `ea-utils` not being found.

---

Following the constant errors being thrown,
Download the .deb file [64-bit version](http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/ea-utils/ea-utils_1.1.2%2Bdfsg-3_amd64.deb) or [32-bit version](http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/ea-utils/ea-utils_1.1.2%2Bdfsg-3_i386.deb) according to the *virtual machine* you are running. Open it inside the virtual machine, and follow the onscreen instructions.

---

Comment: Will do this now after `Software Updater` has finished doing its thing. Yes, that was a typo sorry. Really appreciate your help

Comment: For the first command, it ran loads of downloads, the said `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead`. Second command said: `E: Unable to locate package ea-utils`. I have everything up to date, and ran those two commands.

Comment: from what i can tell, it sounds like poor network connectivity. could you try running `sudo apt-get update` again?

Comment: Same exact terminal responses as before. I also restarted the VM.